# Matlab clc command

Tags: matlab, command

I was checking the original 'clc.m' file in MATLAB. Apparently the function is written as a p-code and you just see the description which is placed in:

```
..\MATLAB\R2013a\toolbox\matlab\iofun\clc.m
```

How can I take a look at the original code?; however this is not the main question, it is just for fun.

The main point is I am looking for a way to reverse the **clc** process, after you clean the screen. Is there any way to reverse the **clc** process. The same question goes for **clear all** as well.

Comment: `clc` is not p-code encrypted. It's a native function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `home` instead of `clc`. Whereas `clc` removes all text from the Command Window and moves the cursor to the top left giving you a blank window, `home` just moves the cursor to the top left and gives a you a blank window - but the text is still there, and you can scroll up to see it. I use `home` all the time rather than `clc`.

In either case, the text remains in the Command History window, and can be retrieved in the Command Window using the Up/Down arrows.

The reason you can't see the code behind `clc` is not that it's p-coded, it's that it's a built-in function (i.e. not implemented in the MATLAB language). The same is true for `clear`, and also many math functions such as `svd`, `eig` etc. There's no way to modify them to change what they do (such as reversing the process).

---

Edit: You might also like to look into the `diary` function, which keeps a log of all the input and output at the command window in a specified file.  I have the following lines in my `startup.m` file (type `doc startup` if you don't know how to use MATLAB startup files):

```
diaryFolder = 'C:\diaries';
diaryFileName = ['diary', datestr(now, 'yyyymmdd'), '.txt'];
diary(fullfile(diaryFolder, diaryFileName))
```

So whenever I start MATLAB, it's automatically capturing all command window input and output to a diary file that's named by the date - If I start MATLAB multiple times a day, it just appends to the same file. I can `clc` or `home` whenever convenient, and there's always a record kept of everything that I can search through if necessary.

Comment: You are right about the 'home' command but is there any limit (buffer limit) for home/clc. (it should be!), how can I know that limitation? On the other hand, Command history just keeps the commands obviously which is not my problem.

Comment: Yes, the default number of lines in the command window scroll buffer is 5000. You can change that in the MATLAB preferences under the section "Command Window". I'm also about to add an edit to my answer with another idea, so see that in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there would be anyway to undo the clc process.  That said, it is possible to still view the command history, so that might get you somewhere.

Once you clear the data, I believe it's gone forever.  I highly doubt that data is stored in memory somewhere.  I know that after a certain number of lines, the history is deleted. So your best bet is to start figuring out how large that buffer is and proceed from there to see if you can find anything interesting.

Comment: I'd guess that `clear` just frees memory rather than overwriting it, so technically the data is still there until Matlab or some other process allocates the same space again.

Comment: @horchler, true. But you have no way of guaranteeing the coherence of what you recover.